# How to connect AWS Lambda with multiple RDS schemas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, sharding

Hi I have a question while using AWS Lambda <-> AWS RDS.
Now I have a connection with one lambda function and one RDS db schema.
In the Lambda function, I have config.py with this json codes.

```
dbinfo = {
   'db' = ~
   'user' = ~
   'passwd'= ~
   'schema' = ~
}
```

Lambda function works for connecting in to the RDS schema , and calling store procedure.

Right now, there is only one schema that I have to connect with Lambda function.
But soon that schema will be changed to a sharding structure.
(ex. game1 schema -> game1 , game2 schemas)

That stored procedure will be stored at both schemas (game1, game2).

How to connect two schemas in one Lambda function?

Comment: If they’re all on the same server but different schemas, just pick one as the default and be explicit with schema and table in your queries. Don’t create multiple connections just because the schema is different. The user account you connect with will need access to all the schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your `config.py` file something like:

```
dbinfo = {
  'shard1' = {
    'db' = ~
    'user' = ~
    'passwd'= ~
    'schema' = ~
  },
  'shard2' = {
    'db' = ~
    'user' = ~
    'passwd'= ~
    'schema' = ~
  },
}
```

and inside of your Lambda, create multiple RDS clients for each shard.

And FWIW, you might want to consider storing your password outside of code in AWS ParameterStore.